# How to read doctype declaration of an xml using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, dtd

Is there a way to read the doctype declaration of an xml using xslt?

Example XML doctype declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD with OASIS Tables with MathML3 v1.1 20151215//EN" "JATS-archive-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd">
```

I need to check if the doctype declaration contains the specific dtd mention above if the condition is true then I need to generate an element in my xml output.

I tried `unparsed-text-lines()` and `unparsed-text()`. Locally it working by supplying the uri of the xml file but in pipeline its not.

Is there a way to read those?

I found saxon:schema function but not sure how use it or if its for xml and xsd combination only not for xml and dtd thing.

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/functions/saxon/schema.html

Comment: Here's the example doctype: <!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Archiving and Interchange DTD with OASIS Tables with MathML3 v1.1 20151215//EN" "JATS-archive-oasis-article1-mathml3.dtd">

Comment: I don't think Saxon itself provides that, there used to be a tool called LexEv that could, I think preprocess stuff like the DTD (that are not part of the XPath/XSLT XDM data model) into nodes of the XDM (I think in the case of DOCTYPE into processing instruction nodes). Depending on the Java version I think the SAX API also has a doctype event by now so it might be easy to set up a filter/preprocessing step to provide the data.

Comment: I believe LexEv is still available as part of the Kernow product (KernowForSaxon) written by Andrew Welch and available from SourceForge. It hasn't been updated in years but since its only dependencies are on stable SAX and JAXP interfaces there's no reason why it shouldn't still be usable.

Comment: `saxon:schema()` isn't going to help. That's only for XSD schema information, not DTDs.

Comment: Of course not. And this is part of the beauty of XSLT (and the XDM it uses). There are also a lot of other details, like the XML declaration, or lexical details like using apostrophes vs. quotes, or denoting an empty element using a short-closed tag or a start-tag immediately followed by an end tag.

Answer (score 1):

The DOCTYPE declaration is not part of the XDM data model, which means it's not part of the document that can be accessed using standard XSLT/XPath constructs.

As Martin points out, it is made available to SAX applications (specifically, by notifying startDTD and endDTD to the LexicalHandler). You could exploit this by writing a SAX filter that converts the DOCTYPE declaration to a suitable processing instruction. Your URIResolver could return a SAXSource that incorporates this filter; the DOCTYPE declaration would then be accessible to the XSLT code as a processing instruction child of the document (root) node.